# Dictionary from list

Tags: python, list

How to create a dictionary from List when my list is like below

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and I want the result as a dictionary like

```
d = {'1':[2,3], '4':[5,6], '7':[8,9]}
```

Is any idea, how to implement this?

Comment: No predefined way to do this, write a loop which increments by 3 and inside that loop add first as key and next 2 elements as value list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = 3
dict = {}

for i in range(0, len(L), n):
#this creates chunks of size n
    sub_list = L[i:i+n]
    dict[sub_list[0]] = sub_list[1:]

print(dict)
```

To get dictionary entries of size `2`, choose `n=3` in this example.

Comment: Thanks I got an required answer

Answer (score 0):

one-liner:

```
dict((L1[i*3], [L1[i*3+1], L1[i*3+2]]) for i in xrange(len(L1)/3))
```

Explanation:

`xrange(len(L1)/3)` returns a lazy range from 0 to 2: `[0, 1, 2]`.
Further for each element `i` of a range it transforms to a tuple `(k, [v1, v2]])`. So the final range will be `[(1, [2, 3]), (4, [5, 6]), (7, [8, 9])]`. And finally we use a `dict` constructor from list of tuples where each element considered as a key-value pair.

Final result is `{1: [2, 3], 4: [5, 6], 7: [8, 9]}`. To convert keys from number to string we need to replace `L1[i*3]` to `str(L1[i*3])`.

Comment: Please explain your code.

Comment: Might also want to suggest a solution for someone using Python 3